# ffmpeg and libvpx: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: centos, libraries, ffmpeg

When I run ffmpeg I get the following error:

`/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libvpx.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Output of `ls -l /usr/lib/libvpx*`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Nov  2 14:10 /usr/lib/libvpx.so.0 -> libvpx.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Nov  2 14:10 /usr/lib/libvpx.so.0.0 -> libvpx.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 409800 Jun 25  2011 /usr/lib/libvpx.so.0.0.0
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is `/usr/local` So it looks like you compiled and installed ffmpeg manually, instead of package manager.

And the problems is that ffmpeg requires a higher minor version of libvpx, recompile ffmpeg will solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember there were compatibility issues between various libvpx-versions and software like  totem, ffmpeg etc. So usually newer versions of libvpx were not installed. You'll have to look for those versions andinstall it by hand.